# Find the derivative of $y={1\over2}\tan^4x-{1\over2}\tan^2x-\ln\cos x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry, proof-verification

> What is the derivative of 
>   $$y={1\over2}\tan^4x-{1\over2}\tan^2x-\ln\cos x$$

What I did here was:

$$\begin{align}y'&=({1\over2}\tan^4x-{1\over2}\tan^2x-\ln\cos x)'\\&={1\over2}\cdot4\tan^3x(\tan x)'-{1\over2}\cdot2\tan{x}(\tan x)'-{1\over\cos x}(\cos{x})'\\&={2\tan^3x\over\cos^2x}-{\tan x\over\cos^2x}+{\sin x\over\cos x}\\&={2{\sin^3x\over\cos^3x}\over\cos^2x}-{{\sin x\over\cos x}\over\cos^2x}+{\sin x\over\cos x}\\&={2\sin^3x\over\cos^5x}-{\sin x\over\cos^3x}+{\sin x\over\cos x}\\&={2\sin^3x-\sin x\cos^2x+\sin x\cos^4x\over\cos^5x}\\&={\sin x(2-\cos^2x+\cos^4x)\over\cos^5x}\end{align}$$

I'm not sure if this is the end, could this be further simplified in some way? And is it correct to this point at all?

**I made a mistake in the beginning while writing down this problem, it should be ${1\over4}\tan^4x$, I changed it out and got exact results**

Comment: 5th line it should be $\cos^5x$

Comment: last line when you factor $\sin x$ you have $2\sin^2x-\cos^2x+\cos^4x$.

Comment: How did you get to that? I got $2\sin^2x+\cos^2x+\cos^4x$

Comment: Ah yes I see, I made a mistake in the last step

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a mistake, the first denominator should be $\cos^2 x \times \cos^3 x = \cos^5 x$ and you should be able to do more factoring then

**UPDATE**

Note after fixing sine power mistake in the last step you have
$$
\cos^4 x - \cos^2 x + 2\sin ^2 x
= \cos^4 x - 3\cos^2 x + 2
= \left(\cos^2 x - 1\right)\left(\cos^2 x - 2\right)
$$

Comment: Yes I see just changed it now, before I saw your answer

Comment: Even after fixing it I still don't know what to do

Comment: @Aleksa see update

Comment: I just checked the results of this from the textbook, the solution is $\tan^5x$, so there is more to do I think

Comment: I got the results, the problem was $1\over4$ instead of ${1\over2}$ made a typo while writing this down and doing it on the computer

Answer (score 2):

$\displaystyle{\sin x(2\sin^2x-\cos^2x+\cos^4x)\over\cos^5x}={\sin x(2\sin^2x-\cos^2x(1-\cos^2x))\over\cos^5x}$ $\displaystyle={\sin^4 x(1+\sin^2x)\over\cos^5x}=\tan^4x(\sec x+\tan x\sin x)$

Comment: Is there something else to do after that point? The solution from the textbook is $\tan^5x$

Comment: I edited my post, there was a typo at the beginning, got the solution after changing everything

Comment: Nothing more. You can clear out the denominator to make it look good. Else the result we obtained earlier should be the last.